# Ambiguity error in C++17 (template template parameters and default arguments issue)

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, language-lawyer, c++17

I have code which is differently interpreted by g++ with the `c++14` and `c++17` standard flags:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class A>
void func(const std::vector<T, A>&v)
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, template <typename>class Vector>
void func(const Vector<T>&v)
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

void f()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    func(v);
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying compile this code with command

> g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp

everything works just fine.

But when I'm trying to compile this code with command

> g++ -std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp

I get this error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'void f()':
main.cpp:19:11: error: call of overloaded 'func(std::vector<int>&)' is ambiguous
     func(v);
           ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: 'void func(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with T = int; A = std::allocator<int>]'
 void func(const std::vector<T, A>&v)
      ^~~~
main.cpp:11:6: note: candidate: 'void func(const Vector<T>&) [with T = int; Vector = std::vector]'
 void func(const Vector<T>&v)
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with this code from the C++17 standard's point of view.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The behavior changed since C++17.

Before C++17, the code works because [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has two template parameters (the 2nd one has the default argument `std::allocator<T>`), while the template template parameter `Vector` is declared to have only one, they don't match then the 2nd `func` won't be considered.

Since C++17 ([CWG 150](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#150)), the default template arguments are allowed for a [template template argument](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_arguments) to match a template template parameter with fewer template parameters. That means both `func` become valid candidates and then leads to ambiguity.

> ```
> template<class T> class A { /* ... */ };
> template<class T, class U = T> class B { /* ... */ };
>
> template<template<class> class P> class X { /* ... */ };
>
> X<A> xa; // OK
> X<B> xb; // OK in C++17 after CWG 150
>          // Error earlier: not an exact match
> ```