# g++ 8.1 template deduction abmiguity with std flag equal to c++17 part 2

Tags: c++, templates, g++, c++17

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893159/g-8-1-template-deduction-abmiguity-with-std-flag-equal-to-c17) and got a good answer but there is a one more not clear point about template parameter deduction in g++ with c++17 flag.

If we will take this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T, class A>
void func(const std::vector<T, A>&v)
{
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
}

template<typename T, typename A, template <typename, typename>class Vector>
void func(const Vector<T, A>&v)
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}

void f()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    func(v);
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Difference in declaration of second template function.
In this case accordingly the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51893159/g-8-1-template-deduction-abmiguity-with-std-flag-equal-to-c17) template parameter deduction should be the same as before. But compiler not report about any ambiguity.

Previous version of second function which produce ambiguity error:

```
template<typename T, template <typename>class Vector>
void func(const Vector<T>&v)
{
    std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
}
```

What I'm missing in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this new set of overloaded functions:

```
template<class T, class A>
void func(const std::vector<T, A>&v)

template<typename T, typename A, template <typename, typename>class Vector>
void func(const Vector<T, A>&v);
```

The first overload is more specialized than the second: the template parameters `T,A,Vector` of the second overload can be deduced if we passed an argument of type `std::vector<P1,P2>` where P1 and P2 are two invented types.

While with the previous set of overload:

```
template<class T, class A>
void func(const std::vector<T, A>&v);

template<typename T, template <typename>class Vector>
void func(const Vector<T>&v);
```

Neither of the two overloads are more specialized than the other. Because the previously described template argument deduction is not realizable.

The ranking of template function is described [here](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.func.order).